# Firebase functions database trigger: PERMISSION_DENIED error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to implement the example of leveraging user authentication information to "impersonate" a user and perform write operations on the user's behalf, using the code straight from the example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

I have been unable to get past permission denied errors. I've tried implementing adminRef as shown in some posts, but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated

[image: error image]

```
exports.impersonateMakeUpperCase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
        .onCreate((snap, context) => {
          const appOptions = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
          appOptions.databaseAuthVariableOverride = context.auth;
          const app = admin.initializeApp(appOptions, 'app');
          const uppercase = snap.val().toUpperCase();
          const ref = snap.ref.parent.child('uppercase');

          const deleteApp = () => app.delete().catch(() => null);

      return app.database().ref(ref).set(uppercase).then(res => {
        // Deleting the app is necessary for preventing concurrency leaks
        return deleteApp().then(() => res);
      }).catch(err => {
        return deleteApp().then(() => Promise.reject(err));
      });
    });
```

EDIT: I am seeing the authType as unauthenticated, despite the fact that I am triggering this db change from a test client app that is signing in with email/pass using firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword, in the cloud functions logs, I am logging out auth and authtype : const authVar =context.auth; const authType = context.authType; Which are showing NULL and UNAUTHENTICATED, respectively.

EDIT: this is also the case if I trigger the db event from the client after authenticating with firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken()

[Firebase onCreate trigger: can't get authType other than UNAUTHENTICATED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565780/firebase-oncreate-trigger-cant-get-authtype-other-than-unauthenticated)

Comment: why not just change the database using admin credentials?

Comment: @WilliamChong I may have to change my approach, but I'd like to understand the reason the example code is not working

Comment: have you checked if your database rules allow user to modify that particular part of db?

Comment: Yes, the rules are just auth != null at this point

Comment: probably either sth wrong with `context.auth` or the rules, mind posting the full rules?

Comment: The rules for this node are {
  "rules": {
    "messages":{
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
    },

Comment: I gave up on trying to get this example to work and used admin creds