# Firebase onCreate trigger: can't get authType other than UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Using a Firebase Realtime Database with these rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "messages": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null"
        }
    }
}
```

And, having this trigger defined as:

```
exports.localOnCreate = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        console.log(context);
    });
```

When I run this on the test website (authenticated via Google):

```
firebase.database().ref('/messages').push().set({
    'hi': 'from-web'
}).then( function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    ...
})
```

I see this in the Firebase Console Functions Log:

```
{
    eventId: '............',
    timestamp: '2018-07-27T20:51:50.943Z',
    eventType: 'google.firebase.database.ref.create',
    resource: {
        service: 'firebaseio.com',
        name: 'projects/_/instances/..../refs/messages/-LISVklGLfbcfrFvnylZ'
    },
    authType: 'UNAUTHENTICATED',
    auth: null,
    params: {
        messageId: '-LISVklGLfbcfrFvnylZ'
    }
}
```

If I am authenticated in the webapp, why am I getting **authType: 'UNAUTHENTICATED',** and **auth: null,** in the trigger "context" (second) argument?

And, as I see in [CloudFunction reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions#.CloudFunction), this function should receive only one argument, an Event object, but it seems it's not the case as seen in [Realtime Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), nor according to my tests.  This last conflict got me completely confused.  Any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could manually call your function through your app instead, so you can pass the auth object to it. [See the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

Comment: I'm having the exact issue. I will let you know what I find. fwiw > v1 takes two arguments. See: Before (<= v0.9.1)

exports.dbCreate = functions.database.ref('/path').onCreate((event) => {
  const createdData = event.data.val(); // data that was created
});
Now (>= v1.0.0)

exports.dbCreate = functions.database.ref('/path').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const createdData = snap.val(); // data that was created
});https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: I have tried authenticating in the client with both email/pass and custom token with the same outcome.

Comment: @RodrigoMata Thanks, but I'd rather keep things as tidy as possible and in this particular problem, I'd rather solve it instead of going around it.  I'm  trying to keep a record of changes (when & what changed, by who; alike an audit log) in parts of the db, so a web/https callable is not an option for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @claytronicon Thank  you for the clarification and your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @RodrigoMata and @claytronicon, this was a bug. I created a github issue and they pushed out a new release v2.0.4 that contains a fix for authType from RTDB events. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pull/304